# Sql to auto increment database field

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I need some help to change numbers in database field for one big database. Database structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `some_product_category` (
  `product_category_id` int(255) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ordering` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_category_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `category_id` (`category_id`,`product_id`),
  KEY `product_id` (`product_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1279345 ;
```

```
INSERT INTO `some_product_category` (`product_category_id`, `category_id`, `product_id`, `ordering`)
VALUES
(2, 1108, 2, 2),
(1, 1108, 1, 1),
(1279344, 1012, 1271372, 1),
(1271373, 1012, 1271373, 1),
(1271374, 1012, 1271374, 1),
(1271375, 1012, 1271375, 1),
(1271376, 1012, 1271376, 1),
(1271377, 1012, 1271377, 1),
(1271378, 1012, 1271378, 1),
(1271379, 1012, 1271379, 1),
(1271380, 1012, 1271380, 1),
(1271370, 1012, 1271370, 1),
```

I need to change ordering field when category_id is the same. For category_id 1012 ordering one must be 1, ordering two must going to 2, ordering three must be 3 and so.

Comment: This sounds like an interesting task, do let us know if you have a question!

Comment: interesting task, but for now without solution :) The question is how to change numbers automatically, is there some way to do it with phpmyadmin or with other script?